# Getting unwanted message "There are trespassing signs. Check it in Observer Settings screen."

Tags: applications

> There are trespassing signs. Check it in Observer Settings screen.

I am getting the above message whenever I open a new app on my Android 4.1.2 Samsung Galaxy Grand DUOS. This has started suddenly when my child was just playing a simple ABC kind of rhymes.

Following things have been tried by me, in the given order, but without success:

1. Check out which was the last 3-apps installed and uninstalled them
2. Cleared App-cache
3. Did a restart

Any pointers or solution is welcome.

Comment: That could very well be a misbehaving app (or rather malware), as you already guessed. Trying a malware scanner might reveal the culprit. From the message, it could also be some "security app" (a true one or one posing as such). Have you installed something like that? // BTW: Googling the message, I found it [here](http://redzmax.com/topic/31837-cerere-traducerexml/), so it belongs to a specific app. Does "RedzMax" ring a bell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is caused by the app [Smart App Protector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sp.protector.free) that maybe you installed and activated an option called **Observer**. Just check the observer and watch who wanted to enter your apps.

Good luck.